# [VBA]how to check if internet disk could be accessed

Tags: excel, vba

To access internet disks with password and ID,and I have a code that is accessing as and below

```
Set wsh= WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
returnvalue = wsh.run("net use address /ID password",0,true)
```

but sometimes when the internet is slow or the password is changed, wsh would not respond and the code just hangs at

```
returnvalue = wsh.run("net use address /ID password",0,true)
```

Consider that passing  the line by after a wait time is terminated and going to next line could prevent the hang on , but I have no idea that whether such API/syntax is existing.

Comment: The best way would be via one of the WNetAddConnection APIs (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/173011) or there is WScript.Network's MapNetworkDrive method. Both will use a reasonable timeout and report back errors.